# Finding how much a larger body slows down when it collides with a number of much smaller bodies

Tags: velocity, collision

A larger spherical body collides with a number of much smaller spherical bodies.

I've just seen this equation, and was wondering if anybody could explain it to me:

$$\Delta v =1-\frac{1}{1+\pi R^2n\frac{m}{M}}$$

Where delta V is the velocity the larger body loses in the collision, R is the radius of the larger body, n is the number of smaller bodies, m is the mass of the smaller bodies, and M is the mass of the larger body.

Comment: Probably need more context. The equation as written doesn't make sense dimensionally.

Answer (score 0):

1. The equation you have written make no sense as [he said](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700633/finding-how-much-a-larger-body-slows-down-when-it-collides-with-a-number-of-much#comment1567922_700633).
2. For collision, I will take "conservation of momentum" into count.

Conservation of momentum says, momentum of two identical objects are equal before and after the collision. So the mathematical expression is
$$m_1u_1+m_2u_2=m_1v_1+m_2v_2 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
The expression is true for two objects. But what if I n numbers of objects?
$$\sum_{i=0}^n m_iu_i=\sum_{i=0}^n m_iv_i$$

Let my second body is at rest. But after the collision will it stay at rest also? Of course not. When a running truck collide with rest bus then bus also starts to move since truck had applied some force to the bus. Since the 2nd object was at rest so initial velocity is $u_2=0 \ \mathrm{ms^{-1}}$.
So $$m_1u_1=m_1v_1+m_2v_2$$
Will both object move at the same direction and with same velocity? If yes, then our equation is $$m_1u_1=(m_1+m_2)v$$ you can find final velocity from the equation. If both identical objects don't move at the same direction and with same velocity then you have to do some algebra to find out first object's final velocity.
$$v_1=\frac{m_1u_1-m_2v_2}{m_1}$$
If second object was not at rest then you have to play(apply algebra) with $\eqref{1}$ to find out terminal velocity.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you have given is incorrect / incomplete. The variables can't mean what you've defined them to mean, and, dimensional analysis aside, the equation implies that the object **speeds up by running into things** (since $1-1/(1+x) > 0$ for $x>0$ and you can't run into a negative number of things or have a negative mass)

---

Momentum is conserved. In a collision between objects $m_0, m_1, ..., m_n$, with starting velocities $v_0, v_1, ..., v_n$, ending velocities $u_0, u_1, ..., u_n$

$m_0 v_0 + m_1 v_1 + ... + m_n v_n = m_0 u_0 + m_1 u_1 + ... + m_n u_n $

Suppose all objects but the first are identical, that is: $m_n = m_1, v_n = v_1, u_n = u_1 \text{ for } n\ge 1$

Suppose a totally inelastic collision, that is, $u_0 = u_1$

Suppose $v_1 = 0$.

Simplify:

$m_0 v_0 = (m_0 + n m_1) u_0$

Solve for $u_0$ in terms of $v_0$ and express the difference as $\Delta v$

$u_0 = m_0 v_0 / (m_0 + n m_1)$

$\Delta v = u_0 - v_0 = v_0(\frac{m_0}{m_0 + n m_1} - 1)$

If you like, divide the numerator and denominator by the numerator to obtain an equation visually similar to the one in the OP.

$\Delta v = u_0 - v_0 = v_0(\frac{1}{1 + n m_1/m_0} - 1)$

---

The $n$ in the OP appears to be the number of particles swept out *per unit area* across the time $\Delta t$ corresponding to the $\Delta v$, to which the $\pi R^2$ term - the cross-sectional area of the sphere - is the conversion factor back to total number of particles in the collision.

Thus defined the equation in the OP is just missing a factor of $- v_0$ on the right-hand side.